# My Google chrome is sharing history with another computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-sync

My sister and I use Google Chrome but our computers are sharing history. All of my browsing history is appearing on my sister's computer and her history on mine. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you set up her box or vice-versa and were logged on as yourself/herself while doing some of the setup.

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to `chrome://settings/search#disconnect`, click `Disconnect your Google Account...` and `Disconnect account`.

It's strange though that you are both logged in with the same Google account -- you should probably check if you are accidentally using her account or vice versa and create (or log in with) a different account.

Comment: It's worth noting that Chrome supports user profiles. You should also consider setting up separate user account on your computer.